# Add key values in a array from outside of array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, wordpress-theming

This is a php question, that happens to involve Wordpress.

My Wordpress parent theme adds a custom metabox. I need to add additional options to the metabox but I need to add the key values options from within my child theme...not in the parent theme where the array is created.

Adding the additional options (key values) in the parent theme is simple, but core theme files have to be changed and therefore will break when the partent theme is updated by the theme developer.

So I have made a child theme that handles all my custom adds...but I have no clue how to inject key vales into an array that is crated in the parent theme.

Here is an excerpt from the the array that builds the options for the metabox (parent theme):

```
$page_meta_boxes = array(
    "Page Item" => array(
        'item'=>'page-option-item-type' ,
        'size'=>'page-option-item-size', 
        'xml'=>'page-option-item-xml', 
        'type'=>'page-option-item',
        'name'=>array(

            'home-page-featured'=>array(
                'main-title'=>array(
                    'title'=> 'MAIN TITLE',
                    'name'=> 'page-option-item-featured-text-title',
                    'type'=> 'inputtext'),
                'main-caption'=>array(
                    'title'=> 'MAIN CAPTION',
                    'name'=> 'page-option-item-stunning-text-caption',
                    'type'=> 'textarea'),
            ),
        )
    ),
)
```

I want to add additional options to the metabox such as:

```
                'get-started-button-title'=>array(
                    'title'=> 'GETTING STARTED BUTTON TITLE',
                    'name'=> 'page-option-item-featured-text-button-title',
                    'type'=> 'inputtext',
                    'description'=> 'The stunning text button will appear if this field is not a blank.'),
                'get-started-button-link'=>array(
                    'title'=> 'GETTING STARTED BUTTON LINK',
                    'name'=> 'page-option-item-featured-text-button-link',
                    'type'=> 'inputtext',
                    'description'=> 'This is a stunning text button link url. This field will be ignored when button title equals to blank.'),
```

Is this even possible?

UPDATE:
What I have tried so far

I am including a file called options.php from within my child theme but its not adding the additional getting-started-button option.

```
$page_meta_boxes['Page Item']['name']['home-page-featured']['get-started-button-title'] = array(
    'title'=> 'GETTING STARTED BUTTON LINK',
    'name'=> 'page-option-item-featured-text-button-link',
    'type'=> 'inputtext',
    'description'=> 'This is a stunning text button link url. This field will be ignored when button title equals to blank.'
    );
```

Comment: Do you get desired output of array $page_meta_boxes? Have you tried adding the element directly into the parent theme(temporarily) just for checking if that works? Maybe the array is included "to late" ?

Comment: In which file do you include the $page_meta_boxes-array ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add additionnal options like this :

```
$page_meta_boxes['Page Item']['name']['home-page-featured']['get-started-button-title'] = array(....);
```

Be aware that even if you don't change the core theme. You rely on the way it is structured. So your code might still break in case of an update by the theme developer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and updated the post with what I did but I can not get an additional option to display.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the possible upgrade breaking my changes but I hope the developer does not make changes to their arrays and variables.

Comment: are you  includind options.php after the definition of $page_meta_boxes ? If you include it before it will be overwritten and without effect.

Comment: As  bestprogrammerintheworld says, it might also be incuded to late, wnen the boxe is already rendered.